# Changing visibility of elements based on which RadPane is selected

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, mvvm, telerik

I have simplified some code and a problem to ask how I would accomplish this - I want my code to be such that when the RadPane Page1 is selected, the RadPane Linked1 is visible, but not the RadPane Linked2 (and vice-versa). What is the best way to accomplish this, keeping in mind that I am adhering to MVVM very strictly.

I have a Telerik RadPane, with two headers, both displaying a different page :

```
<telerik:RadPane Header="Page 1" Name="Page1" IsSelected="{Binding IsPage1Selected, Mode=TwoWay}">
<vws:Page1 />
</telerik:RadPane>
<telerik:RadPane Header="Page2" Name="Page2" IsSelected="{Binding IsPage1Selected, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource NotBooleanConverter}}">
<vws:Page2 />
</telerik:RadPane>
```

I then have a container holding two elements, Linked1 and Linked2, further down the page.

```
        <telerik:RadSplitContainer InitialPosition="DockedBottom">
           <telerik:RadPaneGroup>
                <telerik:RadPane Header="Linked1">
                    <vws:Linked1  />
                </telerik:RadPane>
                <telerik:RadPane Header="Linked2">
                    <vws:Linked1  />
                </telerik:RadPane>                
           </telerik:RadPaneGroup>
        </telerik:RadSplitContainer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working in Silverlight 5, you can achieve this using Ancestor Binding.

```
<vws:Linked1 Visibility="{Binding IsSelected, 
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=telerik:RadPane}, 
                Converter={StaticResource MyBoolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
```